# render canvas or wpf control in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wpf

is their any way to render the canvas or rectangle in wpf in asp.net mvc as an image.

I need to render the wpf control in mvc as an image.

I have tried and only blank image is rendering..

Comment: Can you post a code snippet which may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF-Image-to-WebPage.aspx

Here is the article explains to convert the WPF object to an image in ASPX.